# java.lang.NumberFormatException in my binary progam

Tags: java, exception, binary, numbers, format

I'm really new to Java so excuse my ignorance, but I cannot figure out why my program keeps throwing an error every single time. I'm making a program that converts a string into binary and back. Here's my error. I've tried all sorts of different methods but it always throws the same error. :(

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "010000010001011110010000000010001000"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at main.main(main.java:64)
```

Here's my line of code.

```
int charCode = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(binary), 2);
```

Binary is used with StringBuilder if you were wondering.
Thanks in advance! :)
PS I did try and find similar problems such as mine but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
long charCode = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(binary), 2);
```

Your binary value more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Answer (score 2):

Integer in Java (and almost all other programming languages) is 4 bytes long, it means it can only stores ~`4 300 000 000` numbers, with negative numbers, it is ~ `-2 147 000 000` to `+2 147 000 000`

Number you are inputing is just too big for parsing it into Integer.

---

Also I do not see any reason why you should parse binary code into integer. This should do the trick:

```
    String binaryInput = "10000010001011110010000000010001000";

    long myNumber = 0;
    for (int i = binaryInput.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (binaryInput.charAt(i) == '1') {
            myNumber += Math.pow(2, binaryInput.length() - i - 1);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("And the value is: " + myNumber);
```

---

Output:

```
And the value is: 17473011848
```

Answer (score 0):

How about BigInteger with base '2' ?? Single line of code....

```
String str = "010000010001011110010000000010001000";
System.out.println(new BigInteger(str, 2));
```